# How to try_lock on a boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

As per title, how to try_lock on a boost::unique_lock ?

I've this code:

```
void mySafeFunct()
{
    if(myMutex.try_lock() == false)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // mutex ownership is automatically acquired

    // do stuff safely

    myMutex.unlock();
}
```

Now I'd like to use a unique_lock (which is also a scoped mutex) instead of the plain boost::mutex. I want this to avoid all the unlock() calls from the function body.

Comment: Are you looking for [scoped locks](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.mutexes.mutexes_scoped_lock)?

Comment: I want to use a unique_lock<mutex> over my mutex, something like unique_lock<mutex>myUniqueLock(myMutex); and call a try_lock instead of acquiring the lock on the constructor (as the unique_lock do)

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, if you read the [`unique_lock` destructor reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.unique_lock.destructor) you will see that it unlocks and so can be used as a scoped lock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
boost::mutex myMutex;
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(myMutex, boost::defer_lock);
lock.try_lock()
```

Comment: I get: `error: no matching function for call to 'boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>::unique_lock(boost::shared_mutex&, const boost::defer_lock_t&)'`

Answer (score 10):

You can either defer the locking with the [Defer constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.unique_lock.constructor_try), or use the the [Try constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.unique_lock.constructor_try) when creating your `unique_lock`:

```
boost::mutex myMutex;
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(myMutex, boost::try_lock);

if (!lock.owns_lock())
    return -1;

...
```

Answer (score 4):

Previous answers may be outdated. I'm using boost 1.53 and this seems to work:

```
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lk(myMutex, boost::try_to_lock);
if (lk)
  doTheJob();
```

Comment: Are you saying that the previous methods _are_ deprecated by boost 1.53? This looks identical to my answer above.

Comment: The difference is in lock-type parameter name:  boost::try_lock vs boost::try_to_lock